# How to use Angular4 to Codeigniter view?

Tags: php, angular, codeigniter, typescript

First, I have PHP Codeigniter project currently run on server

Then I've installed latest Angular4 CLI (Typescript) to server 
But I don't know how to integrate with Codeigniter project.

How to use Angular4 in Codeigniter views like an AngularJS?

I guessed, Should I run `ng-build` every time? for use compiled .js file to PHP view

Any Idea?

Comment: I recommend u use codeigniter for building the REST API and let angular handle the views and controller logic

Comment: Angular 4 is a client side framework even through it can do SSR (Server-side rendering). In this case it would be better if you split client from the server and let them talk to each other via Rest API (Session-less approach).

Comment: Can import to view like JS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I missed the first line in your question as I answered in the comment, you already have a project written in CodeIgniter and now you want to integrate Angular 4 as a view into this project.

I think you might be able to try it this way, move your CodeIgniter views to Angular views, and since controller->view in CodeIgniter already communicate via JSON, you should be able to turn your CodeIgniter to web service and send back the response as JSON that will be used later by Angular view.

Sorry but I don't know it can be done in another way or not, hope you find the approach soon. (if possible, I hardly recommend you to separate client from the server)

Comment: Thank you for your idea.