# Angular with CodeIgniter

Tags: angular, codeigniter

I have implemented a project in CodeIgniter 3 which is running in CodeIgniter environment. Now I have installed the latest version of Angular (version 7). I have seen that these two are separate projects. Codeigniter is running in my server using the URL like http://example.com/ whereas Angular is running in http://localhost:4200 (why is this I don't know). My question is:

How to run my project using CodeIgniter environment (like using URL http://example.com/) with the Angular so that I can apply it in CodeIgniter environment?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Angular4 to Codeigniter view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44897148/how-to-use-angular4-to-codeigniter-view)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not just combine these two different frameworks together to work like this.
You can write your APIs in PHP CodeIgniter and consume it inside your angular 7 Project (or any other front end framework).

> Remember Angular is front end framework which only send request to
>   your server for fetching the data.

Comment: I agree with this

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This may resolve my issue if I run the project in Angular environment (like using URL http://localhost:4200) using Codeigniter as back end . But my problem is I have an existing Codeigniter project and so all the design part of this project are done. So how to integrate this into the Angular? Also how do I host it to the server so that it will be run by using the URL like http://example.com.

Comment: To answer your second question first, run ng build inside your root dir, then upload dist folder on your server and then run http server refer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44393334/9144250

Comment: Why you want to have angular if you already have your project in codeigniter

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems to be resolved my issue. I will try it. Actually in my Codeigniter project, a critical graph to be implemented with filtering and annotation. So I am using angular.

Comment: @SuramyaChakraborty great...feel free to mark my answer as accepted by clicking on tick icon and upvote the same. :)